# How I receive the last not NULL record on Android SQLi Database Table Column?

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this code but for now return NULL if found this record :

> TABLE : 1,apple,milk,NULL,fake,NULL,NULL must be return fake.

```
    Cursor cursor = writableDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{str}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: What is the underlying query you are running here?

Comment: you are getting this data `1,apple,milk,NULL,fake,NULL,NULL ` from sqllite ?

Comment: @frankenstein this is a example who I write

Comment: @greg then what you are getting when you call this `getDataTom` method?

Comment: @frankenstein I getting a String with last record on my column on database table friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To SQlite and most relational databases there is no concept of first last or order UNLESS an ORDER BY clause is used.

However, if you want the last non-null then you base the query on

```
SELECT your_column FROM your_table WHERE your_column IS NOT NULL ORDER BY your_sort_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

So turning this into Android you could use [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) :-

```
Cursor cursor = writableDatabase.query(
    TABLE_NAME, 
    new String[]{str}, 
    str + " IS NOT NULL", 
    null, null, null, 
    str + " DESC",
    "1"
);
```

This assumes that the single column is used as the column to :-

- retrieve (2nd parameter),
- the column to test for NULL (the WHERE clause (3rd parameter)(no need to use the 4th which can be used in conjunction with the 3rd)) and
- the column to ORDER BY (7th parameter),

The 8th parameter is the LIMIT clause (note the method generates the SQL with the KEYWORDs so they should not be coded).